# sort time intervals and merge half part

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

I have time intervals and I need to format them as follows

If the current interval inside the compared interval, then delete the current
If the beginning of the current interval inside the compared interval and the end of the current interval not inside the compared interval, then delete the current interval

example:

```
{ 16:55-17:04, 16:00-16:59 } then delete 16:55-17:04
{ 17:00-17:59, 16:55-17:04 } dont delete no one
{ 13:00-14:59, 13:00-13:04 } then delete 13:00-13:04
```

i don't know how don't delete 17:00 interval when compared with 16:55-17:04 and delete only 16:55-17:04 when compared with 16:00-16:59

I know how to check on an element inside only but don't know more.
You can use pseudocode/js(better)/c#/php

Very thanks for any help

Comment: Start by converting the times to minutes. For example 16:55 is 16*60+55 = 1015 minutes.

Comment: it's not a problem, I'm already using it, but i don't know how don't delete 17:00 interval when compared with 16:55-17:04 and delete only 16:55-17:04 when compared with 16:00-16:59

Comment: Also, please pick a language (don't spam tags)

Comment: delete intervals in which only the beginning falls with the compared interval (just like 16:55-17:04 in 16:00-16:59)

Comment: 17:00 is in the interval 16:55-17:04, and 17:59 is not in that interval. So why is the second example any different than the first example?

Comment: I need another logic that the interval falls if the beginning enters the compared interval

Comment: `if(thisInterval.Start >= otherInterval.Start && thisInterval.Start <= otherInterval.End) delete(thisInterval);`